# Not able to fetch Term store and related terms using client object model

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, managed-metadata, term-store, csom

I want to fetch termstore, Termsets and related terms.However, Iam not even able to fetch the termstore. Below is the error message.

> TypeError: termStores is undefined
>
> termStoresEnum = termStores.getEnumerator();

BELOW IS MY CODE----

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>    
$(document).ready(function () {    
    var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_layouts/15/";    
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js", function () {    
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", function () {    
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Taxonomy.js", function () {
                 context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

                 //Call your code here.
                 getTermStores();    
            });    
         });   
    });    
});

function getTermStores() {   
    session = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);
    termStores = session.get_termStores();
    context.load(session);
    context.load(termStores);

    context.executeQueryAsync(function(){   
          termStoresEnum = termStores.getEnumerator();
          var termStores = "Term Stores: /n";

          while (termStoresEnum.moveNext()) {   
                var currentTermStore = termStoresEnum.get_current();
                var termStoreID = currentTermStore.get_id();  
                var termStoreName = currentTermStore.get_name();  
                termStores += "Name: " + termStoreName + " ID:" + termStoreID;  
         }   
    }, function(){    
          //failure loading termstores.    
    }); 
}  
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems it occurs due to the naming conflicts for object `termStores` If to rename  variable `termStores` to, let's say, `termStoreColl`, then everything is working just fine. 
The code below works properly:

```
function getTermStores() {   
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
    var session = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);
    var termStoreColl = session.get_termStores();
    //context.load(session);
    context.load(termStoreColl);



    context.executeQueryAsync(function(){   
          var termStoresEnum = termStoreColl.getEnumerator();
          //The remaining code was omitted for clarity...     


    }, function(sender,args){    
          //Handle errors here...    
    }); 
}
```